# RemoteEndPoint giving wrong IP address

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, tcp, udp

We're using [Fleck](https://github.com/statianzo/Fleck) for our Websockets.

When we test our network program locally it all works fine.  The process of a client connecting is:

- Establish TCP connection
- Send/receive infrequent TCP messages
- Start sending/receiving UDP stream to server

The problem is on the live server which is far away geographically, clients **can** receive and send `TCP` messages, and they **can** send UDP messages, but they **do not** *receive* UDP messages.

We've investigated it as far as we can, and have found that the `RemoteEndPoint` property of the TCP connection on the server has the wrong IP address.  It appears to be an IP address from our ISP.  We use this IP address to attempt to send UDP messages back to the client.  As it has the wrong IP, the client never receives these UDP messages.

The actual source IP address of the client must be known somewhere, as the TCP messages make it back OK.  I've gone through the Fleck source and have printed out the `RemoteEndPoint` of the underlying `System.Net.Socket` but it keeps giving the wrong IP address.

Does anyone know what is going wrong and how we can expose the actual IP addresses of the clients?

Comment: This is by design.  The server and client are communicating with the routers on the Internet behind which are your local networks.  [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) is responsible for bridging the gap between the router and the appropriate internal machine that the communication is directed to.  Is the UDP response sent back on a duplex communication channel, or does the server initiate any new connections to the client?

Comment: @mellamokb the server waits for UDP packets to arrive from client before sending them back.  I'm a little confused why the server can send TCP fine but not UDP, and this unfortunately is a little outside my expertise.

Comment: This is more ontopic for ServerFault. No code issue here, just wrongly setup networking.

Comment: @TomGullen Any chance you remember how you resolved this issue? I have the exact same problem when receiving messages to my server on my local machine from external clients.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reason is that your client does not have a public IP address, but a private address behind Network Address Translation (a very common setup). A common private addresses are of the form 10.X.X.X or 192.168.X.X.

NAT device replaces private address in a packet from your client with its IP address, which is public. For the outside world it seems that the traffic originates from the NAT device. The main advantage of NAT is that it allows many clients to use a single public IP address (IP addresses are sparse). But NAT introduces a problem: an incoming packet needs to be routed to a correct client, but it does not have a client IP address. Some other strategy needs to be used to recognize to which client a packet should be routed and such routing is not always possible.

For example, the most well known limitation of NAT is that you can't simply start a listening TCP server behind a NAT and then connect to it from the outside world. The reason is that NAT device has no idea that your server listens on a given port and thus, it has no way to known that TCP SYN packets from the outside world need to be passed to your client. A workaround for this is to explicitly configure the NAT device to route SYN packets directed to a given port to a specific client (port forwarding).

When a client behind a NAT initiates a TCP connection, a NAT device remembers state of the connection (client address, client port, remote address, remote port). Because of this, when a response arrives, the device knows to which client the response should be passed. When the connection is closed, the device discards state information. This is why your client can communicate over TCP.

But UDP is more difficult to handle because it is connectionless and stateless. When the device sees a UDP packet it does now known if a reply is expected and when, so not all NAT devices handle UDP traffic. Although [there is a technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching) that allows to do it.

To summarize: the problem you are seeing is not C# specific. Setting IP address in packets from your server to the client IP address won't help, because it is most likely a private address that is not routable. To solve the problem you need to use a NAT device that can pass UDP traffic in both directions. But if you are developing a generic client to be used in many setups, you may want to reconsider if UDP is the best option. TCP connection forwarding is a basic feature that all NAT devices support, but some devices may not support UDP.

Comment: NEARLY +1 - your statements on UDB are wrong. They are theoretically ok, but there are well known ways to open UDP. FOr example: Have the client send keepalive packets to the server, the server can then answer. UDP is a common protocol, ther are standards how to communicate with a client behind NAT.

Comment: @TomTom this is true, but I haven't written handling UDP is not possible, I even included a link that describes UDP hole punching technique.